# Image downloaded from web is larger than same image in assets

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uikit

In my iOS app I'm trying to move some images from being included in xcassets to being downloaded from my Wordpress. I uploaded the @2x image from xcassets to the wordpress and I'm running the iPhone 7 simulator. However, when I use the image that has been downloaded from the server I get a larger image then when I use the exact same image from xcassets.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage"];

// is smaller in size than

NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *path = [documentDir stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.png", @"testImage"]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Any ideas as to what's causing this? Or how to fix this?

Comment: What is the contentMode of your imageView?

Comment: Both are unset. So I guess they're the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> I uploaded the @2x image from xcassets

That's the reason!

Lets say your image is 400x400px (pixel) in size. When loading it from asset catalog iOS already know that the image has to be interpreted as 200x200pt (point!), because you defined it in the asset catalog as @2x.

When loading it from server into an image by using the `imageWithData` method as in your code iOS interpret it as @1x -> 400x400pt (point).

Solution:

Tell the image loading the scale factor of your image by using the scale parameter.

```
[UIImage imageWithData:data scale:2.0f]
```

See [Apple API Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624099-imagewithdata)